# How to retrieve all possible Facebook likes categories?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

When requesting a Facebook user's likes through their API, you get a list that looks something like this:

```
{ category: 'Product/service',
  name: 'RunKeeper',
  created_time: '2014-04-05T12:17:09+0000',
  id: '24659131143' }
{ category: 'Science website',
  name: 'I love science',
  created_time: '2014-04-03T08:11:53+0000',
  id: '367116489976035' }
```

...

Since the "Likes" are actually page likes, I assumed that I could simply get a full list of page categories from their https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php page. Once I've done this, I realized that I get likes from categories not in that list.

So, my question is, how can I retrieve a list of all possible Facebook likes categories?

Comment: `I get likes from categories not in that list.` - like?

Comment: e.g. 'Science website'